# How to exclude certain ionic native plugins from a specific platform?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, capacitor, ionic5, capacitor-plugin

We are using the NFC Scanner plugin in our ionic 5 project on the Android platform: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/nfc

How can we exclude this plugin from our iOS platform? Is there a built-in way in Capacitor to exclude certain plugins from a specific platform?
We want to avoid uninstalling the plugin each time when we run 'ionic cap sync ios'.

Answer (score 2):

> It's not possible to "exclude" one plugin, but you can specify the plugins to include, so you should add all the plugins except the ones you want to exclude in includePlugins object. https://capacitorjs.com/docs/config

Source: https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/5084#issuecomment-931288615

`capacitor.config.ts`:

```json
import { CapacitorConfig } from '@capacitor/cli';

const config: CapacitorConfig = {
  appId: 'com.company.appname',
  appName: 'My Capacitor App',
  webDir: 'www',
  ios: {
    includePlugins: ['cordova-plugin-calendar', '...']
  }
};

export default config;
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I found this question too, but thought it might be a bit cumbersome to create an "allow list" list instead of a "disallow list", since we just want to exclude a few plugins. Furthermore, we would need to upgrade to Capacitor 3.0.0. Anyhow, is it necessary to list the dependency of the ionic native + the Cordova plugin? For example for the Calendar plugin: "@ionic-native/calendar" and "cordova-plugin-calendar"? It would be nice to see an example somewhere. I couldn't find any in the docs.

Comment: I have added an example. The array contains the npm package names of the plugins you use. You do not need to add `@ionic-native/calendar` because this package contains only typings. A disallow list is currently not supported. However, you can create a feature request in the github repository.